# AWS Cognito users added in console get 502 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm getting some strange behavior from amazon Cognito and was wondering if anyone had any of the same issues. If I create a user through my app, everything works just fine. But if I create a user in the cognito management console, that user gets 502 errors. What's interesting is that all of the users (regardless of where they were created) show the same verifications in cognito as the ones created through the app. What's even more interesting is that I have the exact same setup in a test environment on a separate AWS profile and have no issues at all. Any ideas? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Are you using custom lambda triggers?